# Random in Random?

Tags: unity-game-engine, random

This script was made to compare player tags and determine if they are active (clones) and select an active clone and rename Rplayer to random players name. But It seems to get stuck on the second random select if a player isn't active. I receive Debug.log (Rplayer 2) Debug.Log (Player tag 1) I have tried swapping it around so it's if (! = null) and rebuilding the code but still no luck same thing. Any Ideas? I feel like I'm just looking at this wrong.

```
if (player.CompareTag("Player1"))
    {
        Rplayer = Random.Range(1, 4);
        if (Rplayer == 1)
        {
            rplayer1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player2");
            Debug.Log("Rplayer 1");
        }
        else if (Rplayer == 2)
        {
            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player3") == null)
            {
                Rplayer = Random.Range(1, 3);
                if (Rplayer == 1)
                {
                    rplayer1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player2");
                }
                else if (Rplayer == 2)
                {
                    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player4") == null)
                    {
                        rplayer1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player2");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rplayer1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player4");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rplayer1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player3");
            }
            Debug.Log("Rplayer 2");
        }
        else if (Rplayer == 3)
        {

            if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player4") == null)
            {
                Rplayer = Random.Range(1, 3);
                if (Rplayer == 1)
                {
                    rplayer1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player2");
                }
               else if (Rplayer == 2)
                {
                    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player3") == null)
                    {
                        rplayer1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player2");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rplayer1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player3");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rplayer1 = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player4");
            }
            Debug.Log("Rplayer 3");
        }

        Debug.Log("player tag 1");
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205713/discussion-on-question-by-sand0rs-random-in-random).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of this comment:

> So I'll try and explain this sorry if it takes 2 comment boxes. You start the game there is an option for 4 players 2 are always active, player 1 player 2. Player 3 and 4 are options to turn on and off, What i'm doing is trying to display an alert when a player lands on a spot <-- Works. The displayed Alert Will get the players name that landed on the spot and enter it into the alert. it then needs to check if player 3 or 4 is active and randomly select 1 player that is not the player who landed on the spot. then activate the alert if (message == 1) { yield return MessageAlert.instance.DisplayAlert(player.name + "Trade Spaces with " + rplayer1.name, Color.blue);

Assuming each player in the game has a Player.cs script attached to it (or something similar), this should be fairly straightforward. Rather than managing players with tags and ids, we can manage the references directly.

First, let's create a method that selects another random player that is NOT the one that landed on the spot. This script can be made as a singleton, or even just attached to the spot.

```
public Player[] allActivePlayers;

void Start()
{
    //Only returns active GameObjects with the Player.cs script attached
    allActivePlayers = FindObjectsOfType<Player>();
}

public Player RandomOtherPlayer(Player excludedPlayer)
{
    //Create a collection of all other active players that don't include the current player
    IEnumerable<Player> activeOtherPlayers = allActivePlayers.Where(player => player != excludedPlayer);
    //generate a random number to select from the new collection
    int randNum = Random.Range(0, activeOtherPlayers.Count());
    //Return the randomly select player
    return activeOtherPlayers.ElementAt(randNum);
}
```

Now when playerA lands on the spot, you can call this to get a random other player.

```
Player playerB = RandomOtherPlayer(playerA);
```

--Disclaimer: If there are any syntax errors please let me know. I typed this in browser and have not yet tested via Unity.

Comment: I will try this out First Thank You! I would rep up but I can't =(

Comment: No worries, @sand0rs feel free to respond with a comment here if there are any questions and I'll get notified and can respond accordingly.

Comment: The Above Script WORKED PERFECTLY! I obviously needed to modify it a little to match up with my current board space script and added the start function into my IEnumerator LandOn function AND BOOM!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU GUYS!!! the Real  major thing that Helps me is the `FindObjectsOfType' rather then pulling the names from the player Script!!!! might not make 100% sense cause you can't see the full project, Trust me it doesn't look like the else if mess XD. THANK YOU AGAIN!!!